# How to identify where (external) units are used in a Delphi XE2 project

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I use JCL Project Analyser to see what units are used in my project, in order to 'clean' it. But, for big projects, I don't really see the dependencies beause I see the units names but not where they are used.
I used Map file but with no success.
Is there any free tool for having used units AND where they are used ?
I tried GExpert Project Dependancies without succes : 
Example : I have JCLInifiles in Project Analyser but I don't see it in GExpert Project Dependancies.

Comment: grep would get this done

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not very easy when you use large library like JCL/JVCL

Comment: Whyever not? Combine `grep` with `for /r` and you've got all you need.

Comment: Pascal Analyzer should do this, but not for free. Peganza also has a free portion of it named Icarus, but I don't know if it has the full functionality needed for this task.

Comment: @UweRaabe Pascal Analyser seems a good choice ...